# Fast DP in Matlab (Viterbi for profile HMMs)

Tags: matlab, profile, hidden-markov-models, viterbi

I've got efficiency problems with viterbi logodds computation in Matlab.

Basically my problem is that it is mandatory to have nested loops which slows the code down a lot. This is the expensive part:

```
for i=1:input_len
    for j=1:num_states
        v_m=emission_value+max_over_3_elements; %V_M
        v_i=max_over_2_elements; %V_I
        v_d=max_over_2_elements; %V_D
    end
end
```

I believe I'm not the first to implement viterbi for profile HMMs so maybe you've got some advice. I also took a look into Matlab's own hmmviterbi but there were no revelations (also uses nested loops). I also tested replacing max with some primitive operations but there was no noticeable difference (was actually a little slower).

Comment: Kevin Murphy's Probabilistic Modelling Toolkit is likely quite a bit faster, as it includes a package called Lightspeed which replaces a number of built in matlab function used in probabilistic modeling with highly optimized versions. https://github.com/probml/pmtk3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, loops just are slow in Matlab (it gets better with more recent versions though) - and I don't think it can be easily vectorized/parallelized as the operations inside the loops are not independent on other iterations.

This seems like a task for MEX - it should not be too much work to write this in C and the expected speedup is probably quite large.